# use function defined in webpack on template page

Tags: webpack, webpack-encore

I'm using `webpack` with `encore`, and I'm trying to define a reusable function in webpack entry and reuse it on templates

> assets/js/app.js:
>
> ```
> import {$, jQuery} from 'jquery';
> import 'modaal/dist/js/modaal';
> import 'foundation-sites';
>
> global.enableAjaxModal = function enableAjaxModal(selector) {
>     $(selector).modaal({
>         type: 'ajax'
>     })
> };
> ```
>
> webpack.config.js:
>
> ```
> var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');
>
> Encore
>     .setOutputPath('public/build/')
>     .setPublicPath('/build')
>     .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
>     .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
>     .addStyleEntry('css/app', './assets/css/global.scss')
>     .enableSassLoader()
>     .autoProvidejQuery()
>     .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.js')
> ;
>
> module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
> ```
>
> twig_template_page:
>
> ```
> <script src="{{ asset('build/js/app.js') }}"></script>
> <script type="text/javascript">
>     enableAjaxModal('.modaal-new-experience')
> </script>
> ```

I'm getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: enableAjaxModal is not defined
```

Comment: remove name from this `function enableAjaxModal(selector) {`. Just `function(selector)`

Comment: @Manoj still getting error message :/

Comment: You are calling this function `enableAjaxModal('.modaal-new-experience')` directly. But you constructed it under `global` variable?
I think it should get called by `global.enableAjaxModal('.modaal-new-experience')`

Comment: still getting Uncaught TypeError :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I resolved this by remplacing the first line of `app.js`:

> `import {$, JQuery) from 'jquery';`

by:

> `global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');`

I think the problem was JQuery import syntax `ES6`, I don't know why because I checked and the syntax is correct...

Anyway thanks for @Manoj and @WhiteRabbit for help, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it to window like that and use it anywhere in your templates :

```
function enableAjaxModal (elem) {
    // your code
}

window.enableAjaxModal = enableAjaxModal ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are extending `enableAjaxModal` function in `global` object.

You should call it with `global` keyword as

```
global.enableAjaxModal('.modaal-new-experience')
```

Another way is to make it an extension of jQuery as

```
$.enableAjaxModal = function (selector) {
    $(selector).modaal({
        type: 'ajax'
    })
};
```

**Usage**

```
$.enableAjaxModal('.modaal-new-experience')
```

**Update**

I see the problem now. `global` is a reserved keyword in node.js which represents an Interface. `global` is basically an interface.
So when you do `global.myFunction()` it will not find it since it has no definition in `interface Global`.

However, You can still modify it by putting your own function as a member property in this interface.

When you go to the definition of `global` it will get you in its configuration file which is named something like`index.d.ts` or `vendor.d.ts` .

Find interface `interface Global`

Extend your function

```
interface Global {
  enableAjaxModal:any
}
```

Now you have access to this function everywhere.

Comment: calling it as `global.enableAjaxModal('.modaal-new-experience')` I'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined`
And for the second propositing I'm still getting `Uncaught TypeError: $.enableAjaxModal is not a function`

Comment: Please specify what is `global` in your question. And for the second problem you need to make sure if jQuery is properly included in the page.

Comment: JQuery is properly included and I'm using it in template... global is the famous NodeJS variable https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_global.asp

Comment: Thanks for your answers, I resolved it by doing this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602580/use-function-defined-in-webpack-on-template-page/50604717#50604717